# Reading a Text File and Updating to a Class using LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a static class:

```
static class ConfigurationDetails
{
    public static string Server;//
    public static string username;// 
    public static string password;//
    public static string folder;//=
    public static string sqlserver;//
}
```

and a textFile with following format:

```
Server = Server
username = administrator
password = "*****"
folder = SPFolder
sqlserver=127.8.9.1
```

I want to read the text File and update the class value, and I am doing it :

```
List<string> c = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Config.txt").ToList();
ConfigurationDetails.Server = c[0];
ConfigurationDetails.username = c[1];
ConfigurationDetails.password = c[2];
ConfigurationDetails.folder = c[3];
ConfigurationDetails.sqlserver = c[4];
```

Probably  the way I have written the code could improve a lot by using LINQ and Lambda. So any suggestions?

Comment: Why not store the configuration in app.config, e.g. see http://geekswithblogs.net/akraus1/articles/64871.aspx (uses [`ConfigurationManager.AppSettings`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.appsettings.aspx))

Comment: @TimS. Client just wants Plain Text File , No xml or No config and no UI. May Upgrade later.

Comment: Working code doesn't belong on stack overflow. You should ask your question on a code review website

Comment: @Dan-o, Can I migrate from here?

Comment: Flag it and ask a mod to move.  Incidentally I really hope that isn't a real password.  If it is, I'd suggest changing it now.

Comment: @ChrisLively, Thnx, None of them are actual

Comment: What exactly do you want to improve? Why do you think LINQ/lambdas can help here?

Comment: @Dan-o I'm not sure I'd call this "working". The `folder` with this solution would be `folder = SPFolder`, not `SPFolder`. It should be similar to an INI parser, that actually reads the name of the key, not just the position in the file.

Comment: @Humanier, Readability and compact code looks clean

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about code reviews and should probably be on a code review site instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure LINQ is the answer to your problems here? This actually looks like a job for [T4 Templates](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davidebb/archive/2008/11/26/fun-with-t4-templates-and-dynamic-data.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

In case you REALLY want some lambdas in your code - check this out ;-)

```
    public void Init()
    {
        var lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Config.txt");
        Array.ForEach(lines, ParseConfigLine);
    }

    private static void ParseConfigLine(string line)
    {
        var separatorIndex = line.IndexOf('=');
        if (separatorIndex < 1)
        {
            // you got malformed line without parameter name - raise an error
            throw new .... 
        }

        Action<string> setParameterAction = null;
        string parameterName = line.Substring(0, separatorIndex).Trim();
        switch (parameterName)
        {
            case "Server":
                setParameterAction = v => ConfigurationDetails.Server = v;
                break;
            case "username":
                setParameterAction = v => ConfigurationDetails.UserName = v;
                break;
            case "password":
                setParameterAction = v => ConfigurationDetails.Password = v;
                break;
            case "folder":
                setParameterAction = v => ConfigurationDetails.Folder = v;
                break;
            case "sqlserver":
                setParameterAction = v => ConfigurationDetails.SqlServer = v;
                break;
            default:
                // unknown parameter - raise an error or ignore;
                return;
        }

        string parameterValue = separatorIndex == line.Length - 1
                                    ? string.Empty
                                    : line.Substring(separatorIndex).Trim();

        setParameterAction(parameterValue);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a little `LINQ`, you should do something like this:

```
static class ConfigurationDetails {
  private static string[] cores = new string[5];
  public static string Server { // = iic-belfort
     get { return cores[0];}
     set { cores[0] = value;}
  }
  public static string username { // = administrator
     get { return cores[1];}
     set { cores[1] = value;}
  }
  public static string password { //= GARBLED
     get { return cores[2];}
     set { cores[2] = value;}
  }
  public static string folder { //= iicservices
     get { return cores[3];}
     set { cores[3] = value;}
  }
  public static string sqlserver { //=127.8.9.1   
     get { return cores[4];}
     set { cores[4] = value;}
  }
  public static void Init(string[] coreData) {
     cores = coreData;
  }
}
//Then do something like this:
var c = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Config.txt")
            .Select(line=>line.Split('=')[1].Trim()).ToArray();
ConfigurationDetails.Init(c);
```